# Tradingview Pinescript quick q

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I would like to plot a base horizontal line at an inputted (changeable) value, then have two lines plot around that line without showing the base line.

So baseline value entered is 1900. I want a line to automatically plot at 1901 and 1899 around that baseline but not showing the baseline (guess you could turn the baseline transparency to zero also). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to plot the baseline in this case.
The script will subtract and add 1 point to your input.

```
//@version=4
study("Baseline +-1", overlay = true)

var float i_baseline = input(1900, "Baseline level")

plot(i_baseline + 1, "Baseline + 1")
plot(i_baseline - 1, "Baseline - 1")
```

Comment: It is giving me this error - Script could not be translated from: |B|var float i_baseline = input(

Comment: Compiles ok on my side. Make sure you copied the first line as well - "//@version=4"

Comment: Ah yes thank you, now how can I go above duplicating this within the same script so that I can have say 20 of these baselines? i_baseline1, i_baseline2, i_baseline3... etc? Thanks

Comment: How might I make these lines all dashed as well?

Comment: 1)Yeah, exactly, create a new pack of input+2plot functions as in the example above, make sure all variable names are unique. 2)Plot()  function doesn't accept dashed styles. You have to go with the line.new(), but thats a totally another question. Take care.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help. Really appreciate it.